# Deserialize JSON data

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I've got a JSON data from Twitter API SEARCH.
I'm trying to deserialize these data into objects.

The JSON scheme looks like this:

```
    {
      "element": INT,
      "element2": STRING,
       ..
       ..
      "Results":[
                   {
                      "user":STRING, 
                      "image":STRING,
                      ..
                      ..
                   }
                ]
   }
```

How could I deserialize those JSON elements into objects using JSON Toolkit or something else?

Comment: Maybe this will help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/json-deserialize-c-sharp][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/json-deserialize-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that matches the JSON schema

```
public class Data
{
   public string Element{get;set;}
   public string Element2{get;set;}
   public List<Result> Results{get;set;}
}
public class Result
{
  public string User{get;set;}
  public string Image{get;set;}
}
```

and use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)  to deserialize

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
```

Comment: The first letter of one of the elements have to be capital letter?isnt it case-sensetive?

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with correct type definition, you can always use dynamic deserialization using Json.Net:

```
var original = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonstring);
```

and then build your desired object based on it (if for example the original one contains overhead information set, and you don't need all of them):

```
var somepart = new {
                       E1 = original.element1,
                       E2 = original.element2
                   };
```

Comment: I dont know how to access "Result" element because it deserialize it still like a JSON.